# Calculate month-over-month or year-over-year differences in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm wanting to calculate time-based comparison metrics in BigQuery and am unclear which of the functions JOIN, LAG, WINDOW is most effective for calculating these common metrics.

I've tried looking at other code written for POSTGRES or other SQL flavors and they aren't working correctly in BQ. The BQ documentation for LAG doesn't show any calculations in the creation of a new field.

Here's an example of what I'm looking to calculate

```
Date Sales
2019-04-01 100
2019-03-01 80
2019-02-01 60
....
2018-04-01 70
2018-03-01 60
2018-02-01 50
```

Performing a month over month comparison should create a third column 'pct_growth'

```
Date Sales Pct_growth
2019-04-01 100 1.25
2019-04-01 80 1.33
```

or a year-over-year comparison

```
Date Sales YOY_growth
2019-04-01 100 1.43
2019-03-01 80 1.33
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could search for the previous month by running a self join looking for a date equals to `DATE_ADD(d.date, INTERVAL -1 MONTH)`:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM UNNEST([
    STRUCT(DATE('2018-01-01') AS date, 300 AS sales)
    , ('2018-02-01', 200)
    , ('2018-03-01', 500)
    , ('2018-04-01', 900)
    , ('2019-01-01', 100)])
)

SELECT *, ROUND(100*(sales-previous_month)/previous_month,2) pct_growth
FROM (
  SELECT *
    , (SELECT sales 
       FROM data 
       WHERE date=DATE_ADD(d.date, INTERVAL -1 MONTH)
      ) previous_month
  FROM data d
)
WHERE previous_month IS NOT null
ORDER BY date DESC
```

[image]

--

Now, with your sample data - it turns out you also have different stores. Do you want to compare the total countrywide, or the total per store?

For the total per store, the fix is:

```
WITH data AS (
SELECT * FROM  `public-data-for-testing.sample_data.sample_data_sales`
)

SELECT *, ROUND(100*(sales-previous_month)/previous_month,2) pct_growth
FROM (
  SELECT *
    , (SELECT sales 
       FROM data 
       WHERE date=DATE_ADD(d.date, INTERVAL -1 MONTH)
       AND Origin_MSA=d.Origin_MSA
      ) previous_month
  FROM data d
)
WHERE previous_month IS NOT null
ORDER BY date DESC
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I can get your recommended fix to work correctly with the sample data table provided, but when I try to swap out the sample data with my table name, the BQ provides an error "Scalar subquery produced more than one element." Here's what I've tried:
WITH data AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM `table_name_here` 
)

SELECT *, ROUND(100*(sales-previous_month)/previous_month,2) pct_growth
FROM (
  SELECT *
    , (SELECT sales
       FROM data 
       WHERE date=DATE_ADD(d.date, INTERVAL -1 MONTH)
      ) previous_month
  FROM data d
)

Comment: That's because you have duplicate months. What do you want to do with duplicate months? Please create a public shared table in BigQuery so I can test with your data.

Comment: Thanks for helping me through this. Here is a sample dataset you should have access to. I tested it on a second account. Please let me know if you have any troubles accessing this dataset. `public-data-for-testing.sample_data.sample_data_sales`